# Something that *logs* network/traffic/bandwidth usage per process?

Tags: software-rec, logging, bandwidth

I have recently found NetHogs, a Linux tool for *monitoring* traffic per process in B/s. But I am looking for something that *logs* traffic per process in total B uploaded and downloaded. (Example, today Firefox downloaded 50 MB, UbuntuOne downloaded 10 MB and uploaded 20 MB...)

Does such an application exist?

Ideally the tool would be FOSS and cross-platform, but feel free to mention OS-specific solutions (e.g. NetLimiter on Windows, which does a bunch of extra stuff too) in case they'll help someone else.

The tool should perform *per process logging*, if it can't do this it isn't a suitable solution. (e.g. Wireshark does not seem to be process-aware)

Comment: You can play with this [small bash utility](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/is-there-a-tool-that-can-monitor-bandwidth-usage-of-a-single-process/6914#6914).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/36586/how-can-i-monitor-network-i-o-usage-per-process-under-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does such an application exist?"

- Linux: None found yet
- Mac: None found yet
- Windows: NetLimiter (commercial)
- Cross-platform: None found yet

See other answers for adapting existing tools.

Comment: Windows: also http://www.bwmonitor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sysinternals' TCPView has a per process column for bytes sent/received. It's log can be saved, but may require some workarounds to allow this to be done while it is running.