# Windows: How do I measure network traffic per process?

Tags: windows, networking, automation

I am developing a benchmarking tool on Windows that measures startup performance of a process. I have been recording total network traffic using `Get-AdapterStatistics | ConvertTo-JSON` powershell cmdlet and it gives me good data:

1. Record current network stats (sum all bytes sent/receved for all adapters)
2. Run my benchmark
3. Record current network stats (sum all bytes sent/receved for all adapters), display the difference

This works fine and I see a strong (0.8) correlation between process startup time and bytes sent. What I don't know is which processes send the data. **How do I get this data?**

What have I considered?

1. *Windows Resource Monitor* - it samples network traffic by process but doesn't save it anywhere
2. *Sysinternals Procmon* - too low-level, also a GUI so a pain to work with
3. *Microsoft Network Monitor 3* - comes with nmcap.exe and could work but trouble is that it actually captures packets which is terribly inefficient
4. *Wireshark* - has stats, but doesn't understand processes

Ideally, I'd like a command-line tool on an API that can either give me total network bytes per process between time A and time B.

Suboptimal is throughput sampling similar to Resource Monitor, but again I need a command-line tool or an API, because I am automating this.

References:

- [Network Traffic per process/application windows](https://superuser.com/questions/618774/network-traffic-per-process-application-windows) - discusses in-proc instrumentation and packet captures
- [Something that *logs* network/traffic/bandwidth usage per process?](https://superuser.com/questions/189128/something-that-logs-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage-per-process) - old question that mentions a single commercial soluition

Comment: Does Glasswire provide granular-enough data?

Comment: I haven't heard of Glasswire but it does look interesting - the website doesn't make it clear if there are command-line tools that come with it but there is something called glasswire.db so if it's a sqlite database then it would be easy to extract the data. However my ask is in a work-related context and installing it would be subject to corporate policy so I'd prefer to go with an Open-Source or direct-from-Microsoft solution of possible.